# inconsistant file extension behavior for HTML5 file input

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

I am trying to make a localhost file upload program so that I can upload files from my phone to my desktop, but I am having an issue with HTML5 file input control.

Here is the code demonstrating the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>File Input Problem Demo</title>
    <script>
let hFileInput = null;    

function performSetup() {
    hFileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
}    

function showFilename() {
    alert(hFileInput.value);
}    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="performSetup()">
    <input id="fileInput" type="file"></input>
    <br />
    <button onclick="showFilename()">show filename</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

On my phone, when I enter the file into the file input, and click the button, it shows the file name **without the extension**, whereas on my primary/host computer, when I press the button, it shows the **full filename including the extension**.

This in turn makes my php upload script to bug out because it fails to find out what extension the file that was uploaded has.

Can somebody please explain this behavior and how I can make it behave more consistantly?

Comment: you shoudln't be testing for file types by looking at extensions anyways. extensions can lie: `ren nastyvirus.exe cutekittens.jpg`. "OH, look, it's a jpg image!". $_FILES contains mime-type information, and you should be examing the actual uploaded file with mime-finding tools, like finfo.

Comment: `alert(hFileInput.files[0].name);` instead of value, which is unreliable.

Comment: @MarcB you're right but knowing mime type alone isn't enough to figure out what extension the file was sent with. a jpeg could have been .jpg or .jpeg which is trivial but still nice to have this information.

Comment: @dandavis tested your proposal and the output of the alert is still without the file extension. I am accessing the page from nexus 6p on chrome app, the page is hosted on XAMPP localhost.

Comment: @MarcB: `hFileInput.files[0].type` has mime info about the file.

Comment: yeah, but you don't need to use the client-provided extension at all. if your mime tool says "image/jpeg", then you go name the server-side file `whatever.jpg`. You don't use/trust the user's extension at all.

Comment: @MarcB yeah but this particular script is personal upload script, and i don't want to discretely go over all possible extensions I want to accept, I want to accept all files without manually deducing extension for each of them.

Comment: @DmitryL i've never seen anything like that. if it's not on `files`, then the OS is stripping it.

Comment: @dandavis i'll check on another browser app.

Comment: @Dmitry: re: "_I want to accept all files_": no, you really really don't want to do that, at least i hope not...

Comment: Actually I notice that this only happens when I try to upload the file via android's filtered file selection which drops the extension. When I use a proper file selector it loads  the extension as well. Strange since I'd think it'd keep the file extension as well... eg when I select "Music" it treats the music files as though they had no extension. i guess the solution is to make a warning message that the file selector is bugged/the file has no extension. Sometimes its ok but nice for user to know when they upload files that have extension without extension.

Comment: @dandavis is there any particular issue from having unprotected file upload behind .htaccess protected page that has no access to internet and is only accessible via localhost? Any method of compromise seems to be minimal compared to the amount of damage that can be caused from their ability to access it in the first place. It's tricky because I want to be able to upload all formats of video, music, text, code(php files disabled via htaccess), and iterating over it all is tricky.

Comment: put that way, and if you cover default files (i've seen default.shtml mapped) +php files, you're probably fine ;)

Comment: @dandavis but ultimately you're the closest to being correct, it's not the OS stripping it but the specific application, eg music file selection/video file selection drops the extension to make the file more readable to the user(supposedly), but in turn it does not send the extension as part of the file name to the upload field. I think it's more of a bug/missed use case that the developers haven't considered  than a universal truth, but nice to know it happens to let the user know to minimize user's astonishment.

Answer (score 0):

Some file selectors omit the file extension when selecting the files. This means the file selector does not provide the file extension information to the file input element which in turn means the file is uploaded without an extension.

The simplest way to handle this situation is to create a warning that appears when a user selects a file without extension information to let them know that their file selector may be omitting the extension, so that they use another file selector(phones/tablets typically let you select what application to select the file with, whereas Windows typically only has a standard selection dialog).

This issue is resolved by making the user use a file selector that does not omit the extension(Music selectors often omit the extension, so do video selectors and photo selectors, whereas generic file selectors tend to keep the extension).

Comment: i think you are referring more to media/gallery/intent pickers instead of file pickers, which are typically used to play contents locally, not upload whole intact files. These are supposed to be rounder, gentler interfaces.

Comment: maybe, but they still allow the user to select the file to be uploaded, and fail to deliver the necessary information to the file selection element, so there is no workaround, the data is lost and the developer has to be aware that this can happen to let the user not get confused when their file fails to upload because it has no extension, or is uploaded without an extension, so the logical conclusion remains the same.

Comment: yeah, i've tapped the wrong one before myself; validate all input ;)